# Getting a hex value from NSColor in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscolor

Does anyone know if it's possible to get a hexadecimal value of the color from NSColor in Cocoa?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Example using blue NSColor:

```
NSColor* color = [NSColor blueColor];

NSString* hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X", 
(int) (color.redComponent * 0xFF), (int) (color.greenComponent * 0xFF), 
(int) (color.blueComponent * 0xFF)];
```

Comment: Be careful! It is not always legal to invoke `-redComponent`, etc on all `NSColor` instances. They may throw an exception. You have to convert to an RGB colorspace and cope with failure. You should see [Technical Q&A QA1576: How do I get the hexadecimal value of an NSColor object?](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1576/_index.html).

Comment: It can be fixed using the `usingColorSpace(:)` method

Answer (score 8):

I like D.A.H 's solution and I make it a computed property instead of a function:

```
import Cocoa

extension NSColor {

    var hexString: String {
        let red = Int(round(self.redComponent * 0xFF))
        let green = Int(round(self.greenComponent * 0xFF))
        let blue = Int(round(self.blueComponent * 0xFF))
        let hexString = NSString(format: "#%02X%02X%02X", red, green, blue)
        return hexString as String
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that this will throw an Objective-C exception if the `NSColor` is not in an RGB color space - Duncan's answer mitigates this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51839877

Answer (score 5):

A solution that doesn't crash due to color space issues:

```
import Cocoa

extension NSColor {

    var hexString: String {
        guard let rgbColor = usingColorSpaceName(NSColorSpaceName.calibratedRGB) else {
            return "#FFFFFF"
        }
        let red = Int(round(rgbColor.redComponent * 0xFF))
        let green = Int(round(rgbColor.greenComponent * 0xFF))
        let blue = Int(round(rgbColor.blueComponent * 0xFF))
        let hexString = NSString(format: "#%02X%02X%02X", red, green, blue)
        return hexString as String
    }
}
```

Comment: The color space correction modifies the color (towards black on my machine) producing a slightly wrong hex string

Comment: The color space should be `sRGB` because it’s used for [Web Colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors)

Comment: @Oskar: usingColorSpaceName is deprecated, what could be done in the new version?

Answer (score 3):

An option is to create an  extension to NSColor

```
public extension NSColor {
    func getHexString() -> String {
        let red = Int(round(self.redComponent * 0xFF))
        let grn = Int(round(self.greenComponent * 0xFF))
        let blu = Int(round(self.blueComponent * 0xFF))
        let hexString = NSString(format: "#%02X%02X%02X", red, grn, blu)
        return hexString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Swift 4

```
extension NSColor {

    var hexString: String {
        guard let rgbColor = usingColorSpaceName(NSColorSpaceName.calibratedRGB) else {
            return "FFFFFF"
        }
        let red = Int(round(rgbColor.redComponent * 0xFF))
        let green = Int(round(rgbColor.greenComponent * 0xFF))
        let blue = Int(round(rgbColor.blueComponent * 0xFF))
        let hexString = NSString(format: "#%02X%02X%02X", red, green, blue)
        return hexString as String
    }

}
```

Comment: usingColorSpaceName is deprecated, what could be done in the new version?

Comment: @Paul I think it's `usingColorSpace(NSColorSpace. ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Gray scale color supported:

```
func toHex(alpha: Bool = false) -> String? {
    if let components = cgColor.components, components.count == 2 {
        let g = Float(components[0])
        let a = Float(components[1])
        if alpha {
            return String(format: "%02lX%02lX%02lX%02lX", lroundf(g * 255), lroundf(g * 255), lroundf(g * 255), lroundf(a * 255))
        } else {
            return String(format: "%02lX%02lX%02lX", lroundf(g * 255), lroundf(g * 255), lroundf(g * 255))
        }
    }
    guard let components = cgColor.components, components.count >= 3 else {
        return nil
    }
    
    let r = Float(components[0])
    let g = Float(components[1])
    let b = Float(components[2])
    var a = Float(1.0)
    
    if components.count >= 4 {
        a = Float(components[3])
    }
    
    if alpha {
        return String(format: "%02lX%02lX%02lX%02lX", lroundf(r * 255), lroundf(g * 255), lroundf(b * 255), lroundf(a * 255))
    } else {
        return String(format: "%02lX%02lX%02lX", lroundf(r * 255), lroundf(g * 255), lroundf(b * 255))
    }
}
```